# Passing data from view to controller using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to send some data on button click to a controller and display the response in a content div back in the view. However i am facing problem while sending the data to the controller. Here is what i am trying to do :

**test.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'get-response',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                "id": "1"
            },
            success: function(response){

                $('#content').html(response.first);
            }
        });

    });

     $("#btn2").click(function(event){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'get-response',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                "id": "2"
            },
            success: function(response){

                $('#content').html(response.first);
            }
        });

    });
    });
    </script>


   <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Button1 Content" />
   <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Button2 Content" />
   <br>
   <div id="content"></div>
```

**route.php**

```
Route::get('ajax-example', function(){
return View::make('test');
});

Route::get('get-response/{id}', array('as'=>'get-response', 'uses'=>'AjaxController@getResult'));
```

**AjaxController.php**

```
public function getResult($id){
    if($id==1){
        $content = "Hello";

    }
    else if($id==2){
        $content = "World";

    }
    return Response::json(array('first'=>$content));
}
```

**Error**
[image]
Can anyone please help me out here. I am a bit confused right now. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you change this line url: 'get-response' to url: 'get-response/2' and then try? and remove data config property in ajax ?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Asik, but i guess i found the solution. I was not handling the url query string properly. So i just added $id = $_GET['id']; and that fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i guess i figured it out what was causing the problem.

I changed my route to

```
Route::get('get-response', array('as'=>'get-response', 'uses'=>'AjaxController@getResult'));
```

and in controller i added

```
public function getResult(){
      $id = $_GET['id'];
```

Now it seems to working just fine :)

Comment: In your Laravel controller you should use $id = Input::get('id');

Answer (score 1):

if you need to get the parameter do this,

```
Input::get('id');
```

and route

```
Route::get('get-response', array('as'=>'get-response', 'uses'=>'AjaxController@getResult'));
```

because your ajax request is something like, `host/get-response?id=5` and this is not compatible with `Route::get('get-response/{id}'..`, because this route needs something like `host/get-response/5`

---

Another way, you can keep your route as u declared and change the ajax request url,

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get-response/'+1,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success: function(response){

            $('#content').html(response.first);
        }
    });
```